# Writing to two variables atomically if a condition is satisfied

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have the following class that is going to be used by multiple threads:

```
public class Container

    private volatile Date date;
    private int amount;
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    public void update(int amount){
        int actualAmount;
        if(check(date)){
              //do some BULK computation to compute the actualAmount
             synchronized(lock){
                 date = new Date();
                 this.amount = actualAmount;
             }
        }
    }

    private boolean check(Date date){
        synchronized(lock){
          //reading from the date and returning true if the date is expired
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure about the correctness. First, I declared the `Date` field as `volatile` to observe changes while performing the condition checking. But it may happen that while doing bulk computation, the second thread tried to perform update causing the data-races.

I don't want to put the `BULK` computation into the synchronized block, because it includes calling a couple of alien methods and prevents JVM from doing optimization.

Performing the bulk computation twice is not going to do harm to the data strctures, but wasting processor's time.

How should I handle this in a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

When bulk computation is finished and another thread has changed amount during that then we have no choice but to recompute amount (rerun this bulk operation), do we?

```
    public void update(int amount) {
    int actualAmount;
    if (check(date)){
          //do some BULK computation to compute the actualAmount
         synchronized(lock) {
            if (check(date)) {
                 date = new Date();
                 this.amount = actualAmount;
            } else {
                update(amount);
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Isn't it a waste of CPU time when two threads perform this bulk operation and one of them should rerun it again?

It may be more efficient to accumulate this update(amount) and when some thread need to read correct amount then recalculate it (run bulk operation).

What thread is going to read this amout? Does it need the latest information?
Knowing the answers may help to design better solution.

Update 1.
BTW, this recursive recalculation may be required over and over. So the most correct way would be to wrap the entire update() body into synchronized statement.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
public class Container

    private Date date;
    private int amount;
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    public void update(int amount){
        int actualAmount;
        Date oldDate;
        // Loop until no one call update() during our computations
        for(oldDate = checkDate(); oldDate != null; oldDate = checkDate()){
            //do some BULK computation to compute the actualAmount
            synchronized(lock){
                if(date == oldDate){
                    // No one update data inbetween
                    date = new Date();
                    this.amount = actualAmount;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /* Return this.date if it is expired or null otherwise */
    private Date checkDate(void){
        synchronized(lock){
          // Check .date and return appropriate value
        }
    }
}
```

Here we store value of `.date` if it is expired. Such way we can check, whether someone have updated data while we perform BULK computations. If he have, we repeat data checking and computations.

If you have to take `lock` in `checkDate()`, then no needs to declare `.date` as *volatile*. If you capable to check date *without locking*, you probably (depending from actual algorithm) should revert *volatile* modifier.

Note, that if you expect that `update()` may be called very intensively, so it has high probability that data will be updated during BULK computations, you need to break loop at some point and perform these computations *under the lock*: performance hit is bad, but *starvation* is worse.